# How to stop powershell terminal from taking input

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

[image: My code looks like this]

[image: let's say I want to input all this text:]

My program takes all input until I say the terminal to stop taking it.

What's the hotkey to stop taking input and send it to the program?

In other terminals I just press ctrl^D, but here it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

[ctrl z + Enter](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/windows-eof-ctrl-d-equivalent)

verified the solution myself

it's called an **EOF (end of file)**

Comment: Thank you, now I also know it's called EOF